# CodeMirror: Select active (focused) editor

Tags: select, editor, codemirror

How can I select active (focused) editor in the page when I have multiple CodeMirror editors?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each codemirror instance and detect focus using `editor.hasFocus()`.